# Laravel Error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

En Laravel 5.4 tengo esta consulta la cual funciona correctamente:

```php
        $list = Friendslist::join('users as usu_A', 'usu_A.email', '=', 'tbl_friendslist.usr_mail_A')
        ->join('users as usu_B', 'usu_B.email', '=', 'tbl_friendslist.usr_mail_B')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_country', 'tbl_country.id', '=', 'usu_B.country_id')
        ->select('tbl_friendslist.*', 'usu_B.name', 'usu_B.last_name', 'usu_B.photo', 'tbl_country.name as city_friend')
        ->where('tbl_friendslist.usr_mail_A', '=', $mail_admin)
        ->orWhere('tbl_friendslist.usr_mail_B', '=', $mail_admin)
        ->where('tbl_friendslist.status', '=', "FRIENDS")
        ->orderByRaw('usu_B.name ASC')
        ->get();

return Response::json($list); 

**RESULTADO:**
[
    {
        "photo": null,
        "id": 1,
        "mail": "cristian@correoprimero.com",
        "name": "Ana",
    },
    {
        "photo": imagen.jpg,
        "id": 2,
        "mail": "diana@correosegundo.com",
        "name": "Carlos Andres",
    },
]
```

Y necesito hacer que el resultado sea algo así (agregar ruta de imagen manualmente):

```php
...
    {
        "photo": /assets/img/imagen.jpg,
        "id": 2,
        "mail": "diana@correo.com",
        "name": "Carlos Andres",
    },
...
```

Y también necesito acceder al correo de cada objeto, para hacer una operación y retornar un valor personalizado, es decir, que en una consulta pueda acceder solo a los índices de todos los correos:

```php
[
    {
        "mail": "cristian@correoprimero.com",
    },
    {
        "mail": "diana@correosegundo.com",
    },
]
```

El **PROBLEMA** que tengo es que si quiero retornar json de solo los correos de los objetos de la consulta, ejecuto:

```php
return $list->mail; 
//ERROR: Property [mail] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

y si intento iterar con for/while/foreach, siempre me trae solo el primer registro...
ACLARACIÓN: Es una API, estos datos los debo retornar en un Json, por eso debe ser desde el controlador. NO los retorno a vista Laravel. 
¿Como puedo solucionar esto? Gracias.

Comment: En cuanto a agregar `/assets/img/` puedes: 1º evaluar si el valor no es nulo y 2º agregar `/assets/img/` al campo mediante la misma consulta. Así no tienes que traer los datos primero y luego modificarlos uno a uno. En cuanto a lo que dices de `mail`, no se entiende.

Comment: If you are trying of get only one register add ->first() instead of ->get()

Answer (score 2):

`$list` es una colección que contiene una serie de objetos. Cada uno de esos objetos tiene el elemento mail. Así que no puedes hacer:

```
$list->mail
```

porque `$list` no tiene `mail`.

Tendrías que hacer:

```
$list->get(X)->mail;
```

donde X es el número del elemento.

Pero esto no es lo que quieres. Para lo que buscas puedes usar el método pluck():

```
$list->pluck('mail');
```

que debería devolverte casi lo que buscas. Pero parece que quieres que te devuelva también el índice 'mail':

```
[
    {
        "mail": "cristian@correoprimero.com",
    },
    {
        "mail": "diana@correosegundo.com",
    },
]
```

Así que deberías probar algo así:

```
$list->mapWithKeys(function($elemento) {
  return [ 'mail' => $elemento->email;
}
```